# Most effective way to get first JPG in directory with PHP

Tags: php, file, directory, jpeg

The question is basically in the title. What is the most effective PHP method to grab the path of first "jpg" image in a directory?

Normally, there would only be a single image in the dir, but in case there were more I would need to make sure it just gets one (doesn't matter which).

Thnx.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, `$imagePaths` will contain all the image paths however just call the first key in the array to get one.

```
    $imageDirectory = "path/to/your/image/dir/";

    $imagePaths = [];

    foreach (glob($imageDirectory . "*.jpg") as $image) {
        array_push($imagePaths, $image);
    }

    // $imagePaths[0] => First image path.
```

**Edit 1**

Turned in to a function it could be something simple like this.

```
<?php

function getImagePaths($dir = "")
{
    // Shorthand if statement to see if $dir is not empty, if it is not we set the parameter value to the $imageDirectory we want to use, otherwise use a default image directory which was specified.
    $imageDirectory = !empty(trim($dir)) ? $dir : "default/path/to/your/image/dir/";

    $imagePaths = [];

    foreach (glob($imageDirectory . "*.jpg") as $image) {
        array_push($imagePaths, $image);
    }

    if (!empty($imagePaths)) return $imagePaths;

    return false;
}

?>
```

**Reading Material:**

[`glob`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)

Comment: Thanks for putting me on the right track. I eventually narrowed it down to the following, which works fine in my case:

```function firstImage($dir){
  $images = glob($dir."/*.{jpg,gif,jpeg,png,svg}", GLOB_BRACE);
  return count($images) ? $images[0] : false;
}```

Answer (score -1):

PHP has functions called `opendir()`, `closedir()` and `readdir()` you could use those and break out after the first file is found.